# Is this condition related to concavity?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an infinitely differentiable function. Consider the condition

> $3 f(\frac{2 x+y}{3})-2 f(\frac{x+y}{2})-f(x)$ is increasing in $x$ for $x\geq y$  .

Is this condition related to concavity ?  If yes how and if not what concept does this condition translate into? ($y$ is fixed but can be arbitrary hence the condition should hold for any $y$). Something like derivative of $f$ being concave or so.

As a related problem it is easy to see that the condition $2f(\frac{x+y}{2})-f(x)-f(y)$ being increasing in $x$ for $x \geq y$ is satisfied if $f$ is concave.